# dynamic allocation of more than 1 dimensional array

Tags: c++, pointers

Here is the code of 2 dimensional array I studied, I also know about pointers to pointers but I am not able to visualize 2d array pointers. Please help me in understanding the dynamic allocation of 2d array.

```
int **arr = new int*[size1];
for(int i = 0; i < size1; ++i) {
    arr[i] = new int[size2];
}
```

Please I don't need just code, please explain it either through explanation or visually.

Comment: [The answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653017/two-dimensional-array-via-pointer) has a picture that can help you.

Comment: Note that a 2-dimensional array and an array of one-dimensional arrays aren't quite the same thing -- one difference is that a 'genuine' 2D array is guaranteed to be rectangular (because it is a single contiguous block of memory), whereas the array of 1D arrays could be "ragged" (in that if you wanted to, you could allocate the various 1D arrays to have different lengths).  The code you posted allocates an array of pointers, and then allocates a 1D array for each of those pointers to point to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You use (*) - c++ create place in memory for this variable. Place is a dynamic, besause you don't specyfiy size variable. Please read this: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/